# How to change the nginx process user of the official docker image nginx?

Tags: nginx, docker

I'm using Docker Hub's official nginx image:
https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/

The user of nginx (as defined in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf) is `nginx`. Is there a way to make nginx run as `www-data` without having to extend the docker image? The reason for this is, I have a shared volume, that is used by multiple containers - `php-fpm` that I'm running as `www-data` and `nginx`. The owner of the files/directories in the shared volume is `www-data:www-data` and `nginx` has trouble accessing that - errors similar to `*1 stat() "/app/frontend/web/" failed (13: Permission denied)`

I have a `docker-compose.yml` and run all my containers, including the nginx one with `docker-compose up`.

```
  ...
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - ./vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/vhost.conf
    links:
      - fpm

  ...
```

Comment: I think the better way is to create your own Dockerfile, that way it is reproducible. You can login to the container and change the user and restart the container, but that might be a maintenance issue in the future.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### FYI

1. It is problem of php-fpm image
2. It is not about usernames, it is about www-data user ID

### What to do

Fix your php-fpm container and don't break good nginx container.

### Solutions

- Here is mine **post with solution for docker-compose** (nginx +
  php-fpm(alpine)): https://stackoverflow.com/a/36130772/1032085
- Here is mine **post with solution for php-fpm(debian) container**:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36642679/1032085
- **Solution for Official php-fpm image**. Create Dockerfile:

  ```
  FROM php:5.6-fpm
  RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
  ```

Comment: After hours of searching helped a lot! I recommend others having same problem as I did (permissions in combination of Docker - nginx - php-fpm) to pay attention here.

Comment: For the `php:rc-fpm-alpine` Alpine linux images, `usermod` does not exist as Alpine uses busybox. Here is the equivalent:


`RUN deluser www-data && adduser -DH -h /home/www-data -s /sbin/nologin -u 1000 www-data` –
Hopefully helpful for those using alpine.

Comment: Why 1000??? Nginx user in nginx container is NOT `1000` so does not have permissions to read the files created by `php-fpm`

Answer (score 11):

I know the OP asked for a solution that doesn't extend the nginx image, but I've landed here without that constraint. So I've made this `Dockerfile` to run nginx as `www-data:www-data` (`33:33`) :

```
FROM nginx:1.17

# Customization of the nginx user and group ids in the image. It's 101:101 in
# the base image. Here we use 33 which is the user id and group id for www-data
# on Ubuntu, Debian, etc.
ARG nginx_uid=33
ARG nginx_gid=33

# The worker processes in the nginx image run as the user nginx with group
# nginx. This is where we override their respective uid and guid to something
# else that lines up better with file permissions.
# The -o switch allows reusing an existing user id
RUN usermod -u $nginx_uid -o nginx && groupmod -g $nginx_gid -o nginx
```

It accepts a uid and gid on the command line during image build. To make an nginx image that runs as your current user id and group id for example:

```
docker build --build-arg nginx_uid=$(id -u) nginx_uid=$(id -g) .
```

The nginx user and group ids are currently [hardcoded to `101:101`](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/stable/debian/Dockerfile) in the image.

Comment: If running alpine nginx add shadow before trying to run usermod. Change usermod line above to: RUN apk add shadow && usermod -u $nginx_uid -o nginx && groupmod -g $nginx_gid -o nginx

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to grab the source from https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx and change the docker file to support build args Ex: of changing the stable Dockerfile of buser release (https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/stable/buster/Dockerfile). to have the nginx user/group uid/gid set as build args

```
FROM debian:buster-slim

LABEL maintainer="NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>"

ENV NGINX_VERSION   1.18.0
ENV NJS_VERSION     0.4.3
ENV PKG_RELEASE     1~buster

#Change NGNIX guid/uid#
ARG nginx_guid=101
ARG nginx_uid=101

RUN set -x \
# create nginx user/group first, to be consistent throughout docker variants
    && addgroup --system --gid $nginx_guid nginx \
    && adduser --system --disabled-login --ingroup nginx --no-create-home --home /nonexistent --gecos "nginx user" --shell /bin/false --uid $nginx_uid nginx \
```

This way is safer than just doing usermod since if something is done in other places like
chown nginx:nginx  it will use the GUID/UID set